# How to read an xml file when all tag names are same using java

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<test name="test">
    <params>
        <param name="credentials" type="list">
            <item>
                <property name="username" value="abc"/>
                <property name="password" value="cba"/>
            </item>
            <item>
                <property name="username" value="user1"/>
                <property name="password" value="pass1"/>
            </item>
        </param>
        <param name="otherKey" value="singleValue"/>
    </params>
```

I can have the param tag where one has items or where one is empty. anyway my question is how to i read the `<item>` tags using java? (there maybe more param tags later with more items)one way is taking a nodelist of tag `<param>`. then taking nodelist of tag `<item>` for those param which has child nodes and using the `getelementbyTag()`.

is there any other way where the second nodelist can be avoided?

if yes then how??

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the second nodelist item you can specify the index of the nodelist you want. which in this case I assume you only want to get the first nodelist. The code would have to be as follows.

> > String username; 
> >     String password;
> >
> > NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("param")
> >
> > Node nNode = nList.item(0); // This will point to just the first
> >     nodelist item
> >
> > if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE)
> >         {     Element eElement =(Element) nNode;
>
> ```
>     username=eElement.getAttribute("username");
> ```
>
> > ```
> > password=eElement.getAttribute("password");
> > ```
> >
> > }